# Change model fields if type is different

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two services: Job and Server. They are quite similar, but Server also has fields "host" and "port". I need the model to recognize the service type, and if it is Job it must set "host" and "port" fields to None automaticly and save it to db table. Is it possible? I`ve tried to use different types of validators in Serializer, but nothing worked.

Here is my model:

```
class Service(models.Model):

    class ServiceType(models.TextChoices):
        JOB = 'Job', _('Job')
        SERVER = 'Server', _('Server')

    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ServiceType.choices, default=ServiceType.JOB)
    code_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    human_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    port = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(65535)])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
```

As you can see, there can be only two types: Server and Job. And I need to automacitally set host and port fields to None, if type == 'Job'. Sounds easy, but I think I`m not expirienced enough to find out the solution. I`ve also tried to use validator in my Serializer, but it didn`t help:

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['type'] == 'Job':
            data['host'] = None
            data['port'] = None

        return data
```

I expect to see host and post fields in database equal to None, if type == "Job"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        if validated_data['type'] == 'job':
            validated_data['host'], validated_data['port'] = None
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

And keep in mind that you must add **blank=True, null=True** for the fields in models that may not be filled with value(in your case 'host' and 'port')

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked, but I`d to write:
            validated_data['host'] = None
            validated_data['port'] = None
seperatly